# Have a trouble with using $bindTo twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I'm new to AngularJs and now I'm trying to work with Firebase.

This is my Firebase data looks like:

```
pavlovdog
|
 ---facebook: "facebook.pavlovdog.com"
|
 ---twitter: "@pavlovdoggy"
```

And my JavaScript code:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['firebase'])

.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseObject','$firebaseArray',
function($scope,$firebaseObject,$firebaseArray) {

    // Syncing to firebase
    var ref = new Firebase("https://#####.firebaseio.com/pavlovdog/");
    var syncObject = $firebaseArray(ref); 
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "contacts");
}])

.controller('NewListCtrl',['$scope', '$firebaseObject','$firebaseArray', 
    function($firebaseObject,$firebaseArray,$scope){
        var ref = new Firebase("https://#####.firebaseio.com/pavlovdog/");
        var syncObject = $firebaseArray(ref);
        syncObject.$bindTo($scope,"newUser");

}])
```

In `DashCtrl` everything is working great and I can use `$scope.contacts`. But in `NewListCtrl` simular code doesn't work. What's the problem?

*I'm using `NewListCtrl` right after `DashCtrl`, maybe it matters*

Comment: Is the problem really binding twice? That is, if you don't bind to `contacts` in `DashCtrl`, does binding to `newUser` in `NewListCtrl` work?

Comment: Problem is w/the the injection syntax for `NewListCtrl`. The function arguments for that controller are not in the same order as the strings in the array. I'm sure this has been answered before... trying to find a duplicate question/answer on SO, but it's harder than it seems :)

Comment: The `$firebaseArray` object doesn't have a `$bindTo` method. When using a collection of items, use `$scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(refToContacts)`. When using a single object *and* three-way binding, use `$firebaseObject(refToUser).$bindTo($scope, "newUser")`.

Comment: But why $bindTo method works in DashCtrl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the surface the first problem is with the dependency injection syntax for `NewListCtrl`.

When you specify the list of dependencies, the order matters. So this line:

```
.controller('NewListCtrl',['$scope', '$firebaseObject','$firebaseArray',
```

Is stating that Angular should inject three items into your controller when creating it, and in that specific order.

Notice, however, that your function arguments are not in the same order in this controller:

```
function($firebaseObject,$firebaseArray,$scope)
```

This is sure to cause things to go haywire in your code. What you think is the `$scope` is really `$firebaseArray`, and so on.